# strftime: wrong unix timestamp

Tags: sqlite

In SQLite, I get a wrong unix timestamp when I execute the query `SELECT strftime('%s', 'now')`.

For example, `SELECT datetime(strftime('%s','now'))` returns: `3691373-43510960-18 12:00:00` instead of something like `2012-10-11 12:34:56`.

Is it a bug?

Thanks in advance.

- PHP v.: 5.3.4
- SQLite Library: 2.8.17
- OS: Win7, 32-bit.

PS: `SELECT datetime('now')` returns a correct current date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The timestamp returned is correct; `datetime` *seems* to be not working because `%s` returns a Unix epoch, but without other specifiers, `datetime` will take it as a Julian day.

If you do,

```
SELECT datetime(strftime('%s', 'now'),'unixepoch');
```

then you will get the correct results. See [SQLite3's datetime function page](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).